# android studio gradle plugin problems out of the box

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

just installed android studio after getting a fresh install of win10. i created a new empety project and got this error:

> Gradle sync failed: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version:
> '7.2.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

this is the code:

> ```
> plugins {
>     id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
>     id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
>     id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
> }
> ```

Edit: the sources were blank and the path to the file is C:\Users\RK33DV\AndroidStudioProjects\test\build.gradle

Comment: Hi @PugMc, please add more details to your question by clicking [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73141600/edit) button. 1) What are the "following sources" in your error message? 2) What's the name and location of the shown file?

Comment: Please also show your `settings.gradle` file if it exists. Usually it has the same location as `build.gradle`.

Comment: @Vadik settings.gradle doesnt exist in my project for some reason

Comment: I've created a new empty project, and if i delete `settings.gradle` file I will get your error. Try to recreate your project again or try to create missing `settings.gradle` file from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73142436).

Comment: It might also be helpful if you add to your question the version of Android Studio you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're missing `settings.gradle` file. Try to add `settings.gradle` file to your project root directory with the following content:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "projectName"
include ':app'
```